# How to check the integrity of a download with GPG4Win, e. g. Tor?

Tags: tor

Yes, I read the instructions on the Tor site and was not able to follow them. No pics or vids. But installing Tor is useless when not knowing if it is fake or not. Instructions using the cmd.exe, GPG4Win comes with a GUI, though. 
What to do-do you know better instructions? Step-by-step?

Thanks a lot for your advice!

Comment: [The TOR projects explains it better than I could](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en). Did you read this? When you did, what exactly didn't you understand about it?

Comment: Read exactly that, why is it not feasible via GUI? Started cmd.exe, pasted "C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --keyserver x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290", result is, roughly translated: Command "C:\Program either wrong spelled or could not be found".